# Trying to add width and height attributes to SRC

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add width and height to a URL path var inside .attr() and can't get the sytax right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(this).attr('src',lstAlbumart + ' + width="250" height="250" +');
```

Won't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to size an image?

Comment: Yes and I forgot (CRS) chaining jQuery. Thanks to Explosion Pills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for adding multiple attributes simultaneously is to pass an object.

```
$(this).attr({
   src: lstAlbumart,
   width: 250,
   height: 250
});
```

You could also chain `.attr` calls, but that is less efficient.